# Using Wires in PHP Laravel 9.10 / Livewire 2.10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a question in a bigger project while using livewire. For testing I created a new laravel 9.x projekt with livewire 2.x. I just want to klick the button and get the output "test".

If I create a second blade-file "test_overview.blade.php", import the "test.blade.php" there and change the path in the web.php, it works. But I dont want to have a second file for every formular or list.

I'm afraid I'm lost on this one.

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', App\Http\Livewire\Test::class)->name('test');
```

app.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

test.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div>
    Test
    <button wire:click="submit" type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
</div>
@endsection
```

Test.php (Controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change type to button (`type="button"`)?

Comment: the same, nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Your route is not rendered as a Livewire component, because you explicitly tells it to run render the `render()` method, which returns the view.

Livewire will always run the `mount()` and lifecycle hooks, before running `render()` on its own. You should therefor only specify the class that should be run (and Livewire will use its internal constructors to set everything up).

```php
Route::get('/', App\Http\Livewire\Test::class)->name('test');
```

Comment: Tanks! I changed the route, but it dont work. The mount()-Method is called, but its not empty. What I must do in the mount()-Method?

Comment: What did you change the route to? Clearly the code you've provided doesn't reflect your actual code, which makes it harder for us to actually see what's wrong, since we don't see the full picture

Comment: Sorry, I changed the route to your example:


Route::get('/', App\Http\Livewire\Test::class)->name('test');